# Problem with request from Subcollection in Firestore

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Hey I try to fix a Problem I need to get a subcollection based on a query before.

```
 const kurzRef = collectionGroup(db, 'kurzwaffensub' );
 const FirstOperation = query(kurzRef,where("kurzModell", "==", `${kurzModell}` ));
    


const getWaffenDaten = async () => {
    const modell = await getDocs(FirstOperation);
    const data = [];

for (const doc of modell.docs) {



  const parentDoc = await getDoc(doc.ref.parent.parent);
  const { Name, avatarPath } = parentDoc.data();

  // Thats the code snippet which I have my problem with 
  const  waffenbilderRef = collection(db, 'users', doc.data().uid, 'waffenbildersub')
      let subCollectionDocs = await getDocs(waffenbilderRef)
  // 


     data.push({
       ...doc.data(),
          Name,
          subCollectionDocs,
          avatarPath
     });
```

The documents which I get with the first operation have a String Fieldvalue of the `document ID`

After that I need to get the subcollection based on the Fieldvalue `document ID`
Which is one of 3 subcollections which you can see in the picture.

[image]

Unfortunately I get something back which I dont fully understand

[image]

As you can see I get the `subCollectionDocs`, but it doesn't display the Data.

You can see next to the `RED marked Arrow` that there are 2 Documents in the result of the `subcollectionDocs`. This is right but I don't know how to retrieve the data properly.

Comment: you need to pass reference "users/waffenbildersub"  instead of just "users" inside your collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're adding the full `DocumentSnapshot` from the subcollection query to your state, which is what then shows when you `console.log` it.

My guess is that you're expecting to just see the document's data and ID, which you can do with:

```
const subCollectionDocs = await getDocs(waffenbilderRef)
const subCollectionData = subCollectionDocs.docs.map((doc) => {
  return { id: doc.id, ...doc.data() };
}
console.log(subCollectionData);

 data.push({
   ...doc.data(),
      Name,
      subCollectionData,
      avatarPath
 });
```

Comment: Yeah I just want to get the Data from it. But now I get ```Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): subCollectionDocs.map is not a function``` back.  Im trying to get this code to work for ages but Im not able to do it :DD. I also used ```foreach``` as well but then I get same error that it is not a function.

Comment: Oops, you need a `docs` in there, as what you call `subCollectionDocs` is actually a `QuerySnapshot` object. Check the updated code.

Comment: Now it works thank you very much. Your my hero :D